# How does charAt reverse the input in this method?

Tags: java, methods

```
//method
public static String foo(String s)

{
if (s.length() == 1)

return s;

else

return foo(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0);
}
```

What does foo(“abcd”) evaluate to? 
It is is my understanding that this would reverse the input, but why is that?

Comment: Just walk through each line step by step.  When you call foo("abcd"), what happens?  Does the if() check go into the "return s" or "return foo(...)..." section?  If it goes into the second case, what happens then?

Comment: Interesting corner case for `foo("")`. (And `foo(new String(new char[10*1000*1000]))`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [*recursive*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) reverse. `s.substring(1)` is the line without its first character; `s.charAt(0)` is the first character.

What the function is saying is "if the line is one character long, the answer is the line itself; otherwise, chop off the first character, compute the same function, and add the chopped off character to the end of the result".

You can work out on a piece of paper how performing the steps above amounts to reversing a string.

**EDIT :** It is worth noting that this implementation is going to crash with an exception if you try passing it an empty string. Changing `if (s.length() == 1)` to `if (s.length() == 0)` would address this problem (thanks to Tom Hawtin - tackline for mentioning this in a comment).

Answer (score 3):

You are facing [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) here!

Each level of the recursion is appending the first character to the end, and invoke a recursive call on the suffix of the string.

In your example, the call stack will look something like that:

```
s = "abcd" => append 'a' to the end, and invoke on "bcd".
s = "bcd" => append 'b' to the end, and invoke on "cd".
s = "cd" => append 'c' to the end, and invoke on "d".
s= = "d" => return "d" as it is.
```

when you go back from the recursion, you actually append it in reverse order:

```
return "d"
return "d" + 'c' (="dc")
return "dc" + 'b' (="dcb")
return "dcb" + 'a' (="dcba")
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this makes it clear how the recursion works in this case:

```
foo("bcd") + "a"
  (foo("cd") + "b") + "a"
    ((foo("d") + "c") + "b") + "a"
      (("d" + "c") + "b") + "a" -> "dcba"
```